# Fastest way to search for an element in unsorted array

Tags: algorithm, visual-c++

I just bumped on to this question today and was trying for a solution that is better than O(N) but could not come up with one.

Searched through SO but couldn't find this question.

Is there any solution better than O(n) or is it a problem that cannot be solved better than that?

My initial thought was Binary Search but again for that you need to sort it which is again >n. I also thought of applying quicksort for just the half of the array to which the search element might belong but again we are making n comparisons initially and discarding the other half only later. Am I getting this right or am I looking at the solution in a wrong direction?

I was trying for a solution in c++ and no javascript's IndexOf() or C# Array.find() or LINQ's.

Comment: I don't think you can do better than `O(n)` if it isn't sorted.

Comment: How about searching from both ends of the array, and meeting in the middle if the element is absent. it would work on an array of a fixed size or a circularly linked list.

Comment: @user6001430 double time of comparations

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Make it parallel. Divide the array in chunks and search in parallel.
The complexity will be O(n) but running time will be much less. Actually it will be proportional to no. of processors you have.

You can use [Parallel Patterns Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492418.aspx) in C++

Comment: I bet it will become memory bound before you get any significant speedup.

Comment: @Mysticial in that case you can distribute the search over a cluster and divide the file in chunks if its large enough.

Comment: Yes I also thought about breaking the array and trying threads with them but thats not an algorithmic perspective of this problem. Thats again implementation specific like IndexOf() or find()

Comment: @MuhammadHasanKhan it will not be proportional to the number of CPU cores that will be involved. See Amdal's law - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl%27s_law

Answer (score 11):

You're right, the fastest way is to simply iterate through the array and look for it.  Without further information, there is nothing better you can do.

Unless you have a [quantum computer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grover%27s_algorithm), that is.

Comment: I would hope that you wouldn't be programming that quantum computer in C++

Comment: If you're gonna count parallelism, then yes, you can do better than `O(n)` time. :)

Comment: @Mysticial unless you have a number of processors comparable to `n` (that is, a countably infinite number of processors), it's not going to change the asymptotic time.

Comment: Sometimes I wonder if anybody actually pays any attention to what the `O` actually means. -_-

Answer (score 6):

If you're searching for one element once, just iterate through it.  No possible way to get it faster.

If you're searching multiple times, it would be worth it to index it (or sort it, if you will) and make the following searches fast (log(n)).

Comment: Yeah... You are right...But finding a way to do it for just once might be amazing and could also be used n times without even using binary searching on indexed numbers.

Comment: It's impossible.  Not impossible as in "It's impossible for you to jump 3 meters in the air", because that could happen with lots of steroids and a bouncy floor, but impossible as in 1 + 1 can't equal 3.

Comment: ha ha...! Agreed. I just posted this problem to find whether I was the only person to get struck with this or are there more ? :P

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. "If you're searching multiple times" is the decisive factor.

Answer (score 3):

If it's not sorted, you have to inspect each element.

Answer (score 3):

Usually, we check one element of array in one iteration... which takes n iterations to completely loop through the array...
therefore, worst case time complexity becomes O(n).

```
for(int i=0;i<s;i++){   // s = array size
    if(arr[i] == n)     // n = element to be searched
        return i;
}
```

but what I experimented is check multiple elements in a single iterations.
let's say 5 elements per iteration. so, in that case the for loop will look like,

```
// s = array size
// n = element to be searched
for(int i=0;i<s;i+=5){  // notice the increment in i here...
    if(arr[i] == n)   
        return i;
    
/* check the next four indexes as well as if arr[i] is the last element of the array */ 
    else if( arr[i+1] == n && i+1 < s)
        return i+1;
    else if(arr[i+2] == n && i+2 < s)
        return i+2;
    else if(arr[i+3] == n && i+3 < s)
        return i+3;
    else if(arr[i+4] == n && i+4 < s)
        return i+4;
}
```

here, theorotically time complexity should become O(n/5)...

but, when I executed the program by taking array of size 1000000 with the elements 1 to 1000000 arranged randomly and calculated the time taken by both the loops for different test cases of same array size... these were the results!

One element per iteration

1. Time Complexities(in micro-seconds) : 4105 4180 4108 4115 4087 4137 4094 4089 4141 4167 4082 4084 4114
   4118 4099

5 elements per iteration

1. Time complexities(in micro seconds) : 1318 1382 1384 1297 1364 1289 1351 1617 1300 1289 1395 1385 1349 1329 1369

So, as I saw, it makes significant change in time complexity!

Comment: O(n/5) is actually O(n). Big O notation measures complexity as variables approach infinity. Infinity over 5 is still infinity. Execution time, while very important and variable, as you point out, is something different.

Comment: sounds like a classic case of "benchmarking in debug mode"

Answer (score 1):

If you are not doing parallel search, then you can insert key to the end of array as sentinel value and do search with only 'n' comparisons instead of 2n comparisons.

For more details, refer the following question:
[What's the point of using linear search with sentinel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33329349/whats-the-point-of-using-linear-search-with-sentinel)

Answer (score 0):

You can search an element with O(1) using this approach.

Just create  a **MAP** . When you insert a value just then for that key assign value to '1', and to search it again just check if that array is present or not .

Below is the code:-

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    map<int,int> map;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        int k;
        cin>>k;
        map[k]=1;
    }
    int num;
    cin>>num;

    if(map[num]){
        cout<<"FOUND"<<endl;
    }else{
        cout<<"NOT FOUND"<<endl;
    }

    return 0;
}



Input: 
5    // *no. of elements*
6 4 7 3 2  //*elements* 
3    // *number to find*
```

Output :**FOUND**

Comment: This assumes that you have extra memory. Typically not good for large arrays. This isn't usually a good trade in unless the number of searches is high enough.

Comment: If you are searching the number in the array then  you can apply this to .

Comment: According to the documentation for map in C++: Search, removal, and insertion operations have logarithmic complexity. so not O(1).

Answer (score 0):

This could be solved by using some tricks. In an unsorted array simly if we traverse through it, the complexity in worst case (when element is present at last index) would be O(N), where N is the size of array. So, here is the trick. First check the last index so that if the element is present at last index (the worst case) our code will be executed in O(1). and after that while the code to traverse and find the element. So, now the worst case complexity would be O(N-1).

```
int findElement(int N, int arr[], int element){
  if(arr[N]==element){
    return i;
  }
  for(int i=0; i<N-1; i++){
    if(arr[i]==element)
      return i;
  }
  return -1;
}
```

Comment: This is still O(n). If the number is at n-1, then you will have looked at n numbers.

Answer (score 0):

While looking for some faster method than linear search, I've just stumbled upon the "front-back" linear search method (https://medium.com/@insomniocode/search-algorithm-front-and-back-unsorted-86d7a4bfc258) which I tested on a few instances and turned out to be really faster but not significantly. Worth a try in my opinion!

Answer (score -1):

Yet,there is another logic...

**(Even numbers are stored in even address)**

- First check whether the search element is odd or even
- If the search element    is"even",then perform search only for even
  adress(Create loop    increment to skip odd address)
- Half the element can be skipped from searching by this logic

For example:

- If there are 100    element stored in unordered way and search
  element is 98....  since    the search number is even...u can skip
  all odd address(so 50 elements    are skipped) Now the search is done
  only for rest 50 even address....

You can divide the element and search in parallel or Use "pivot key"    to sort to rest 50 elements or any other search method

Comment: Unsorted array: 8 32 4 3 14

Comment: Even using half the elements, it would still be O(n).

Answer (score -1):

What will be the efficiency of algorithm that makes use of partition approach applied during quick-sort as follows?

1. Randomly select some value (let us call it v) in the list.
2. Partition the entire list into 2 parts. Left part contains all elements that are less than v. Right part contains all elements that are greater than v.
3. Repeat the steps 2, 3 until you determine whether the element exists or does not exist.

I am not sure about the complexity of above algorithm, but looks like it will be definitely less than the complexity of quick-sort algorithm: (n log n).

Comment: That's only for sorted arrays. Unsorted array are like: 8 32 4 3 14

Answer (score -2):

Given the following array, you can just do parallel searching.

```
const array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 3];
const search = 3;

for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  if (array[i] === search) {
    console.log(i);
    break;
  }
  if (typeof array[i + 1] !== "undefined") {
    if (array[i + 1] === search) {
      console.log(i + 1);
      break;
    }
    if (typeof array[i + 2] !== "undefined") {
      if (array[i + 2] === search) {
        console.log(i + 2);
        break;
      }
      if (typeof array[i + 3] !== "undefined") {
        if (array[i + 3] === search) {
          console.log(i + 3);
          break;
        }
        if (typeof array[i + 4] !== "undefined") {
          if (array[i + 4] === search) {
            console.log(i + 4);
            break;
          }
          if (typeof array[i + 5] !== "undefined") {
            if (array[i + 5] === search) {
              console.log(i + 5);
              break;
            }
            if (typeof array[i + 6] !== "undefined") {
              if (array[i + 6] === search) {
                console.log(i + 6);
                break;
              }
              if (typeof array[i + 7] !== "undefined") {
                if (array[i + 7] === search) {
                  console.log(i + 7);
                  break;
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Will you put 20000 ifs if the array is 10000 elements long?

Comment: This is still O(n).

Answer (score -5):

It is possible to make your program run faster than `O(n)`.

You start off by sorting the array using the merge sort algorithm, then you use binary search to find the element. Both algoro have a running time of `O(log_2(n))`. Adding these two complexities together, you get `2*log_2(n)`, which is `O(log_2(n))` with the witness `C = 2`.

Comment: Merge sort complexity is O(n * log(n)). Get your facts right before calling *all* wrong. Also you can't sort array if you need it's original order, which depends on task at hand. Doesn't it seem natural to you that sorting needs more work than searching? Sorting would make sense only when no. of searches is high (more than a certain threshold).

Comment: Yes, I forgot the merging function. But binary search still has a running time of O(log_2(n)). Adding this to the running time of merge sort, you get n*log_2(n)+log_2(n), which equals O(n*log_2(n)) with the witnesses C=2 and n_0=0, which is pretty good.

Comment: Well, O(n * log(n)) is worse than O(n) of a linear search.