# Binary search or Linear search on large unsorted lists?

Tags: java, search

I understand that the **Binary search** is more efficient than the **Linear search** in a **sorted list** and a large list, but what if we have a large list but **not sorted**, which one we use linear search or binary search?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm

Comment: In that case using Binary search will be pointless. So the answer is use Linear search.

Comment: Did you mean to ask: "If we had a large unsorted list, would it be more efficient to sort the list and then preform a binary search, or to just use a linear search?". In that case a linear search would be better.

Comment: @DonatPants - Depends on the number of linear searches to be done. If it's `n` linear searches, then time complexity is O(n^2), in which case it's better to sort first with time complexity O(n log(n)) or if radix sort can be used, O(n).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The concept of **binary search** can only work on **sorted inputs**. Just research how it works: [Binary search at Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm).

Based on your original question "*binary search or linear search on unsorted lists?*" the answer clearly is **linear search** because **binary search** can not be used.

However could it be possible that you at least have **some knowledge** of the **input structure**? If *yes* you could use that to create a better solution. If it is completely random then obviously linear search is the best. But you could easily parallelize the search like seen here: [Fastest way to search for an element in unsorted array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7656791/fastest-way-to-search-for-an-element-in-unsorted-array).

---

Let me give you a small overview for binary search. I select a random number between **1 and 100**. You can now guess the number and I will tell you if my number is lower, equals or greater than your guess.

**Binary search** would now guess the half of the search interval, **50**. I answer the guess is **too high**. The search interval is now from **1 to 49** and binary search now goes for **25**. It repeats the search until the element is found.

---

If your input is **unsorted** then this will not work anymore because if I tell you that my element is lower than **50** then it does not necessarily mean that it is stored **left to 50**, it could also be **to the right** because the input is **unsorted**.

Here is an image illustrating the algorithm (found by a quick Google search):

[image]

Comment: Thanks it really helped

Answer (score 1):

*Binary Search* by definition only applies to sorted sequences. It is a prerequisite that the list you binary search on has to be sorted, otherwise binary search does not work at all.

So to answer you question: **On unsorted sequence linear search is the way to go**

**But** keep in mind that, if you have to perform a number (say M) of searches then it might be good to sort the list once and then use binary search on it.

Imagine you have to perform `M` searches on an array of length `N`. -

- Using *linear search* would cost `N*M` (M searches each costing N).
- *Sorting* + *binary search* would cost `O((N log N)+(log N)*M)` -> `(N Log N)` for sorting the list, plus `M` searches each costing `Log N`

When is it convenient the former and when the latter? when `N*M >N log N+(log N)*M`.

Comment: I like that you mentioned the scenario where one needs to search multiple times on the same input.

Answer (score 0):

In that case **Linear Search** will be more efficient, because its complexity is `O(n)`.
But, for **binary search** the array needs to be **sorted**. For sorting the best complexity will be `O(nlogn)`, and the search in `O(logn)`, which when added gives `O(nlogn)`.
So, clearly **Linear search** is better here.