# C++ efficient finding of the first nearest matching value in a vector?

Tags: c++, algorithm, performance

Given the unsorted vector {6.0, 3.02, 4.2, 5.3} and given a threshold of 0.1, how can I efficiently find the first match to the value 3 (for example) within the given threshold  in C++ ?
My current implementation is as follows but it is of complexity O(n). I want to improve that to O(log n) if possible. Thanks a lot in advance

```
std::vector<double> array = {6.0, 3.02, 4.2, 5.3};  
double val = 3 // the to be found value within the array above
double thresh = 0.1; // max threshold of the matching value
double found; // the matching value
for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++){
    if ( abs(array[i] - val) < thresh){
        found = array[i];
    }
}
```

The output should be 3.02 because it is the first closest match to 3 in the given array within the allowed threshold of 0.1

EDIT: If I can afford sorting the vector upfront, how can I re-implement the above search to be O(log n)? Thanks

Comment: I don't think it's possible to beat O(n) without first sorting the array

Comment: If array is unsorted or specially organized any way you must scan all elements.

Comment: Data is given as vector? if so, no luck

Comment: Btw be careful with `abs()` if you use one from C library it rounds number to `int`

Comment: Your question doesn't match the implementation - your algorithm finds the _"first existing value within 0.1 of `val`"_, not _"closing existing value to `val`"_

Comment: If you are generating the date somewhere, you can save some time by searching while generating, that's all. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45267908/binary-search-or-linear-search-on-large-unsorted-lists

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I now edited the question to the case where I can afford sorting the vector up-front. Are are then any recommendations to improve my linear search. Thanks

Comment: As a rule, I rarely write the code for the OP. You'll learn the most from following the prompts in comments and answers, and figuring out how to write it yourself! The docs will help you. :)

Comment: It's not possible to do better than `O(n)` with an unsorted array since you always have to look at all the elements. If your array is sorted, do a binary search. I'm sure there are plenty of materials out there that can teach you how to implement one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As sad by others, you can't do better than O(n) search without sorting the array.

If we sort the array first, we can do binary search and adopt a new strategy.

We need to find out which one is the first value in the array that satisfies (array[pos] >= (value - threshold) ). If we can find such value, then we check if it is inside the range [value - threshold, value + threshold]. If it is we return it, otherwise we don't.

Below is how I would implement with the sorting, using C++.

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <math.h>
#include <limits>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

double binarySearch(std::vector<double>& array, const double value, const double threshold) 
{
    // I assume here that the array is sorted ...
    // If I cannot find it, I will return infinity (:

    double returnValue = std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity();

    std::vector<double>::iterator it = std::lower_bound(array.begin(), array.end(), value - threshold);

    if(it != array.end() ) 
    {
        if(fabs(*it - value) <= threshold ) returnValue = *it;
    }

    return returnValue;
}



int main() 
{
    std::vector<double> array = {6.0, 3.02, 4.2, 5.3};    
    double val = 3.0;
    double threshold = 0.1;

    // Sorting the array
    std::sort(array.begin(), array.end() );
    double res = binarySearch(array, val, threshold);

    if(res != std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity() )
    {
        std::cout << res << std::endl;
    }
    else std::cout << "Desired value not found" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You're performing a linear search, which is definitely `O(n)`. However, that is unfortunately the fastest search algorithm for an unsorted array/vector.

Therefore, to get something faster, you're going to need to first sort the vector. **Do this up front, one time, or your resulting code will actually be slower than linear search.** `std::sort()` is reasonably efficient - although there are a handful of faster sorting algorithms, if you care to find one. Be sure you're actually storing the sorted vector, either in place, or in a new variable, depending on your needs. **You do not want to have to sort the data more than once.**

Then, you can use a binary search algorithm to locate the value. `std::lower_bound` or `std::upper_bound` will probably suit your needs (thanks Eric for that note). Otherwise, if you're using standard binary search, even if the exact match isn't found, it'll put you in the ballpark where you are looking at two or three values, one of which is definitely your match.

Now, as Eric pointed out in comments, sorting does cost more than a linear search, so if you're only searching that data set *once*, you already have the most efficient approach.

---

EDIT: In comments, the OP described needing to add new data to the vector on occasion. This is a fairly simple issue to resolve: simply use a binary search to find where the new value belongs in the *sorted* vector, and insert it there.

Comment: Sorting is O(n log n), so unless you can pay this cost up front once, it's better not to sort.

Comment: Yeah, I was getting at that, but I'll clarify that.

Comment: If you search only once, do not sort it. That is the rule.

Comment: Yup. I clarified that in there, @kelalaka. Thanks for that reminder.

Comment: "use the binary search algorithm" - `std::lower_bound` or `std::upper_bound` would do the job here

Comment: @Eric Fair enough. I work more with raw implementation than standard library in my line. Incidentally, those use binary search under the hood, but that's an implementation detail that the average user wouldn't necessarily know. Info added.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I now edited the question to the case where I can afford sorting the vector up-front. Are are then any recommendations to improve my linear search? Thanks

Comment: OP: Saw your comment above, actually, and responded there. You're about as efficient as you can get with a linear search. See the docs for use of `std::sort()`, `std::lower_bound`, and `std::upper_bound`.

Comment: @user3134575 Use a binary search as stated in the third paragraph of this answer. Look up documentation or tutorials if you don't know how.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendations. The problem is that in my code I need to add new values to the array occasionally (i.e it is a growing array) but I'm searching through the array for matching values (within a threshold) more frequently than adding new values to the array, so I guess I might afford sorting up-front everytime a new value added. I guess I need to use a specific kind of sorting algorithm, not the standard one, because the array will be almost sorted everytime a new value is added.

Comment: @user3134575 That's actually a simple problem to solve: **use binary search as part of your insertion**. Instead of sticking the value on the end, find where it belongs *first*, and then insert it there.

Answer (score 0):

I think it cant be done. The best you can improve the search in a sorted array is *O(log(n))* using binary search. But in an unsorted array you eventually must go through all the array items, and this is *O(n)*

Comment: binary sort or binary search?