# Fastest way to find a zero element in an array with 0 and 1 unsorted?

Tags: c, algorithm

I want to find a good solution for this, that I have a large array with 0 and 1 element and it random and unsorted. I want to find the 0 element in array, not care about the position of element just find 0 element quickly as possible.
Example input:

```c
uint8_t array[N] = {0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0};
```

So the output can be 0, 2, 3, 5, 8, or 10 is true. If I use for then I have a time complexity in O(n), that my array in fact is large so any solution that for better performance. I not a family with algorithm, I searching for some common search algorithm and them normal sorted array number. So I can't apply these algorithm to my problem. I can use more space complexity that trade-off for time complexity then we have any better solution?

Comment: If the array elements are truly random, then the odds of finding a 0 in the first 10 elements is 99.9% and the odds of finding a 0 in the first 20 elements is 99.9999%. If the array elements are not truly random, then you have more information, and you need to share that information.

Comment: I do not undertand "the output can be 0, 2, 3, 5, 8, or 10 is true". Do you want a list as output or do you mean that finding any of the listed numbers is an acceptable result?

Comment: Please explain more about the background of the array. I understand you cannot sort it. How is it created? Can you keep track of the first 0 while creating it?

Comment: @user3386109 Yeah it not truly random, it like flag of status of a slot. Then 0 is we can use that slot, and 1 is not. The 0 then go to 1 if slot filled, and if slot release we set this position of array to 0.

Comment: @Yunnosch Yeah, one of the output is can.

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand "one of the output is can". Could you rephrase?

Comment: Note, adding the need to fill zeros with 1s has changed the question, because the characteristics of the data in the arrays has changed in a way that influences optimisation strategies. I have updated my answer, luckily it still was applicable. If you now add the information that 1s can also turn back into 0s, then the question is changed to the point were it invalidates an existing answer (admittedly mine). That would qualify the question as a "moving target", which is not appreciated on StackOverflow. In that case please keep this question as is and create a new one with all info.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fastest way to search for an element in unsorted array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7656791/fastest-way-to-search-for-an-element-in-unsorted-array)

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Yeah I try to clear to my question.

Answer (score 2):

O(1) can be achieved if you can change the data structure and fill the new data structure instead. Here I assume that the data in your array has been created and stored in the shown array; and that this storing activity can be suitably changed (otherwise yes, an O(n) operation ONCE cannot be avoided) so that the activity of looking for zeros then can be speed-optimised.

I propose to change the array from storing 0-or-1s into an array which stores only the indexes of the zeros. Accompanied by an integer variable with the total number of (already) filled entries you still have the complete information as stored in the shown array.

Finding a zero (or all zeros) is then just reading the first/next index of a zero.

In order to cover this intention "The 0 then go to 1 if slot filled, and if slot release we set this position of array to 0." as described in your comment, you can keep a counter of already used zero indixes (which hence are now 1-filled).
If that counter reaches the number of stored values (not of stored zeros), you know that all slots are taken.

If you then add the need to turn random 1 back into zeros again, this speed-optimised data structure cannot do the job anymore.

Only if you are lucky, in being able to select the slots which are going to be freed (unlikely I assume) you can turn the whole concept into a ring-buffer. But I assume that this is not the case.

Answer (score 0):

O(n) is the only way to go.
If you want to improve performance, you can use threads to parallel searching.

For example if you have an array of 10k items, you can make it 10 times faster by creating 10 threads, each thread will process 1k items.

It is similar to Parallel MergeSort / MapReduce.

Comment: There's another way to parallelize the search: You can make it 8 times faster by using bits instead of ints :)